# Лишние символы в char

Tags: c++

Пишу программу, которая должна принимать `user input` и обрабатывать его.
Но возникли проблемы, когда ввожу в переменную `char` 11+ символов — она перегружает ввод, как я понимаю, в следствие чего, я не могу ввести символы в `str1`. Если убрать `cin.clear()`, то я и в `str2` не могу ввести что-либо.
Как решить эту проблему?

```
string str1, str2;
char ch[11];                                                            

cout << "Please write some characters (1 - 10)." << endl << "> ";
cin.getline(ch, sizeof(ch));                                                //enter any characters
cin.clear();

cout << "Please, enter any text." << endl << "> ";
getline(cin, str1);                                                         //enter 1st string
cin.clear();

cout << "Please, enter any text one more time." << endl << "> ";
getline(cin, str2);                                                         //enter 2nd string
cin.clear();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверяйте `falibit` и пропускайте лишние символы. Или используйте std::string.

```
cin.getline(ch, sizeof(ch));
if (cin.fail())
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Comment: Отлично, работает, но как? О.о

Comment: @KoryJaxx Почитайте, как работает ignore и getline